# Oracle PL/SQL: Trigger Syntax

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I'm kinda new(like 1 year of experience) in PL/SQL and i have to make a kind of tricky trigger, and i want to check if my syntax is correct, mainly the selects, inserts and variable value store i make .

So, i want to have a trigger that, when i insert a new row on a table, i have to make a select to that table to store inserted values into 2 variables i created:

```
create or replace trigger schema.trg_CP 
          after insert on "schema"."tdlrp"
          referencing old as old 
          for each row
          
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
          declare 
          v_fkidnc                       schema.tdlrp.fkidnc%type;   
          v_errortype                    schema.tdlrp.xerrort%type;
          v_fkerrorID                    schema.tepm.ferror%type;
          v_linerror                     number;
          v_pr                           schema.tpm.pipm%type
          v_pkdocid_r                    schema.tddr.pidr%type
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          
          begin
            if inserting then
              select fkidnc, xerrort
                into v_fkidnc, v_errortype
                from schema.tdlrp;
              --
```

This is correctly made, right?

After that i have to make some `if-elsif` validations:

1. `if v_fkidnc = 1` and `if v_errortype = 1` i have to make a set of selects and inserts in a row
2. `if v_fkidnc = 1` and `if v_errortype = 2` i have to make another set of anothers selects and inserts, but the logic is all the same to every `if-elsif` validation:

```
create or replace trigger schema.trg_CP 
          after insert on "schema"."tdlrp"
          referencing old as old 
          for each row
          
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
          declare 
          v_fkidnc                       schema.tdlrp.fkidnc%type;   
          v_errortype                    schema.tdlrp.xerrort%type;
          v_fkerrorID                    schema.tepm.ferror%type;
          v_linerror                     number;
          v_pr                           schema.tpm.pipm%type
          v_pkdocid_r                    schema.tddr.pidr%type
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          
          begin
            if inserting then
              select fkidnc, xerrort
                into v_fkidnc, v_errortype
                from schema.tdlrp;
              --
              if v_fkidnc = 1 then
                if v_errortype = 1 then
                  select ferror, fipcm
                  into v_fkerrorID, v_linerror
                  from schema.tepm;
                  
                  select pipm 
                  into v_pr
                  from schema.tpm
                  where fipcm := v_linerror;
                  
                  insert into schema.tddr(pidr, fipc, xuser, datea, fiptm) 
                  values(schema.seq_tddr.nextval, old.fipc,'A', systimestamp, v_pr);
                  
                  select pidr
                  into v_pkdocid_r
                  from tddr 
                  where fiptm := v_pr; 
                  
                  insert into schema.tere(pidr, ferror, fidre, xuser, datea, fipcm) 
                  values(schema.seq_tere.nextval, v_fkerrorID, v_pkdocid_r, 'A', SYSTIMESTAMP, v_linerror);
                  
                elsif v_errortype = 2 then
                 select...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE;
  
END trg_CP;
```

For example: on these 2 `select` i made:

```
if v_errortype = 1 then
                  select ferror, fipcm
                  into v_fkerrorID, v_linerror
                  from schema.tepm;

                  select pipm 
                  into v_pr
                  from schema.tpm
                  where fipcm := v_linerror;
```

i'm assigning values to `v_fkerrorID` and `v_linerror` (first select). On the second `select` i want a condition `where fipcm` is equal to the variable value i stored on the first `select`:

```
select ferror, **fipcm**
into v_fkerrorID, **v_linerror**
```

After that i want to make `insert` to another tables with the values i stored in above queries:

1. Before the second `insert` i have to make a `select` to the table where i first inserted to get the `v_pkdocid_r` value for the second `insert`

   ```
   insert into schema.tddr(pidr, fipc, xuser, datea, fiptm) 
   values(schema.seq_tddr.nextval, old.fipc,'A', systimestamp, v_pr);

   select pidr
   into **v_pkdocid_r**
   from tddr 
   where fiptm := v_pr;
   ----------------------------
   insert into schema.tere(pidr, ferror, fidre, xuser, datea, fipcm) 
                 values(schema.seq_tere.nextval, v_fkerrorID, **v_pkdocid_r**, 'A', SYSTIMESTAMP, v_linerror);
   ```

Am i doing it correctly?

Edit 16/09/2022

With all the suggestions, i changed my trigger to this:

```
create or replace trigger schema.trg_CP 
          after insert on tdlrp
          referencing old as old new as new
          for each row
          
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
          declare 
          v_fkerrorID                    schema.tepm.ferror%type;
          v_linerror                     number;
          v_pr                           schema.tpm.pipm%type;
          v_pkdocid_r                    schema.tddr.pidr%type;
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          
          --
          begin
              --
              if :new.fkidnc = 1 then
                if :new.errortype = 1 then
                  
                  select ferror, fipcm
                    into v_fkerrorID, v_linerror
                    from schema.tepm; --this select only inserts one row to each variable
                  
                  select pipm 
                    into v_pr
                    from schema.tpm
                   where fipcm = v_linerror;
                  
                  insert into schema.tddr(pidr, fipc, xuser, datea, fiptm) 
                  values(schema.seq_tddr.nextval, old.fipc,'A', systimestamp, v_pr);
                  
                  select pidr
                    into v_pkdocid_r
                    from tddr 
                   where fiptm = v_pr; 
                  
                  insert into schema.tere(pidr, ferror, fidre, xuser, datea, fipcm) 
                  values(schema.seq_tere.nextval, v_fkerrorID, v_pkdocid_r, 'A', SYSTIMESTAMP, v_linerror);
                end if;              
              end if;
              --
  
END trg_CP;
/
```

But i'm getting:

PL/SQL: ORA-00984 on:

```
select pipm 
  into v_pr
  from schema.tpm
 where fipcm = v_linerror;
```

the problem is not on the select statement, i removed both selects after both ifs, and now it tells me that the collumn is not allowed on the if statement... if i remove both ifs, turns me back to error on select statements

The error is when i put this insert:

```
insert into schema.tddr(pidr, fipc, xuser, datea, fiptm) 

values(schema.seq_tddr.nextval, old.fipc,'A', systimestamp, v_pr);
```

after this select:

```
select pipm 

into v_pr

from schema.tpm

where fipcm = v_linerror;
```

Comment: `old.fipc` must be `:old.fipc`. You can skip `referencing old as old new as new`, because it is just the default.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select the based table within the (row-level) trigger.

Instead of

```
select fkidnc, xerrort
into v_fkidnc, v_errortype
from schema.tdlrp
-- no WHERE condition? It will fail if one inserts more than just one row.
```

use

```
v_fkidnc := :NEW.fkidnc;
v_errortype := :NEW.xerrort;
```

When you use `after insert on "schema"."tdlrp"` then schema and table names are case-sensitive - which is possible but rather uncommon for Oracle.

`"schema"."tdlrp"` is different to `schema.tdlrp`. Oracle default object names to uppercase.

This does not make any sense:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE;
```

Just skip it, the code will behave (almost) the same.

Instead of

```
select ferror, fipcm
                into v_fkerrorID, v_linerror
                from schema.tepm; --this select only inserts one row to each variable
              
              select pipm 
                into v_pr
                from schema.tpm
               where fipcm = v_linerror;
              
              insert into schema.tddr(pidr, fipc, xuser, datea, fiptm) 
              values(schema.seq_tddr.nextval, old.fipc,'A', systimestamp, v_pr);
```

you can simplify as

```
insert into schema.tddr (pidr, fipc, xuser, datea, fiptm) 
select schema.seq_tddr.nextval, :old.fipc, 'A', systimestamp, pipm
from schema.tpm
where fipcm = (select fipcm from from schema.tepm);
```

Comment: Edited my question, can u please check?